# Should I create another model for admins? Or what's the best way to do it in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, architecture

I'm developing an app, which requires two types of users `regular user` and `admin`. Regular users have roles in the app, and an admin doesn't have any roles, he just should have an access to an admin panel.

What's the best way to implement this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your question can have a wide range of answers to it, yet I shall suggest you the following:

You can use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for authorisation and access management, or you can use [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)

There is however another option [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify), which is used for role management and can be used in conjunction with `cancan`.

One alternate could be using [activeadmin](http://activeadmin.info) for the admin, and any authorization gem(`cancan`,`pundit` etc) for the `regular user` access management.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I find it useful. Do you think I need divide those users into two models `Admin` and `User` or it would be redundant?

Comment: you have that option, I think you should stick to a single user model, differentiating it by roles

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would probably be to just have a boolean field in your User model called `admin`. When you can do that you can just do something like this:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  <%= render 'admin_panel' %>
<% end %>
```